# object convert to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

**Input :**
I have one object like below .Its converted to another format

```
var a={
"p1":"1",
"p2":"2"
.
.
.
"p1000":"1000"
}
```

**Output :**
I need to covert above object to like this output format
    p1=1
    p2=2
    .
    .
    .
    p1000=1000

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please briefly explain what your need is, and also share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can iterate on object and then concatenate the string

```
 var a = { "p1":"1", "p2":"2","p1000":"1000" }
    var format = "";
    for(var i in a) {

        format += i + " = " + a[i] + ' \n';
    }
    console.log(format):
```